# jquery - conditionally enable a field

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields on my form - I'd like to only allow users to enter field2 if field 1 has valid data. How can I achieve this using jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//cache the second field to make the event handler perform faster
var field2 = document.getElementById('field2');
$('#one').on('change', function () {

    //check to make sure the value is "valid"
    if (this.value == '') {

        //if not valid then disable the input
        field2.disabled = true;
    } else {

        //if valid then enable the input
        field2.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gL8Jq/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Thanks - this is pretty elegant

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#input-one').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "valid value")
      $('#input-two').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
   else
      $('#input-two').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Senad thanks - this works - if I set input-two to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

What data do you want to have in field1, i.e. in what format? Depending on that you need to write a validate function, that you should call on field1's onblur. This validate function should check the data in field1, and enable/disable field2 appropriately.

i.e. Something like:

```
$('#field1').blur(function() {

  var data = $('#field1').val();

  var valid = false;
  // ... do you validation here ...

  $('#field2').attr('disabled', !valid);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This basic structure might work for you:

```
$('#field1').change(function() {
  if (isValidData($(this).val()) {
    $('#field2').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#field2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}).change();
```

I don't think the whole `disable` business is very clean. Does anyone know of a cleaner solution?

Comment: You could hide it: {display:none}.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the `change` event of field 1 and perform validation. Then, set the "disabled" attribute of field 2 based on the results of your validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('id_field_2').change(function(){
    if ( !is_field_valid($('id_field1').val()) ) { 
        $('id_field_2').val('');
    } 
});
```

you can use "change" or other keybord event line keydown, keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For example if you want to enable 2nd textbox only when 1st textbox is not empty.

```
$('#text1').blur(function(){
  if( $(this).val() == '' ) { // for example empty textbox not allowed
    $('#text2').val('').attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $('#text2').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

#### Demo